# How can I provide a tag that would run my cucumber background once for all scenarios?

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am using cucumber-js
I have some slides within the same url. For my feature, I want to provide the tester a way to open a url, and then have multiple scenarios on the same url:

The problem with the solution below is that the url re-opens for every scenario, reseting the slide to the start. I can never test each slide step as a separate scenario.

Any help or suggestion appreciated: example:

Feature: Valuation slide user journey - pre-reqisite As a developer I want to open the url /valuation/

```
Background:
    Given I open the url "/valuation/"

Scenario: Test valuation slide button
    Given the element "valuationIntro" is visible
    When  I click on the button "valuationIntro.cta"
    Then  I expect that element "valuationSlide1" becomes visible

Scenario: Test valuation autocomplete
    Given the element "valuationSlide1.cta" has the class "invalid"
    When  I set "jk5 7kj" to the inputfield "valuationSlide1.autocomplete"        
    Then  I expect that element "valuationSlide1.cta" does not have the class "invalid"
```

I understand I can use tags, but not entirely sure how I can use a tag to run a background once.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to have the second test continue where the first one left off. This is bad practice and cucumber does its best to make it hard for you. Each test should be independent and running a test should not leave side effects on the system. That being said, for performance reasons, your background step could of course privately save whether or not it has been run already and do nothing on subsequent executions.

Comment: thanks, how can the background step detect if it has run or not?

Comment: Personally I make wide usage of singletons to share code between cucumber steps. Being singletons, they can maintain arbitrary state throughout a test run. Since this is nodejs, unless you are exporting constructors, most modules are effectively singletons.

Comment: I have the same approach but I can't see how I can detect even in a singleton, whether the background has run, and if so don't run it again.

Comment: hopefully the answer helps clarify...

Answer (score 0):

```
var executed = false;

var myStepDefinitionsWrapper = function () {
    this.Given(/^I open the url "([^"]*)"$/, function (url) {
        if (!executed)
            // do some work with url
            executed = true;
    });
};
module.exports = myStepDefinitionsWrapper;
```

Just a simplification to make a point. I would use singletons with state.

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes in my background I am opening a url. How do I detect for all 'Background's no matter what it does, when it has executed?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you're looking for a generic way to solve this problem, without writing code, then I don't know and I also don't think it's a good approach. HTH.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestions. I happen to think it's filling a gap that is missing in automated testing. There is no reason why cucumber can't be used to describe the tests themselves. I don't see any good argument why it's a bad idea, other than "it wasn't designed that way". So what. It can be used that way.

Comment: It has nothing to do with cucumber. If tests are not isolated you will quickly lose control of what is causing failures when things don't go as expected because it will be very hard to track down the cause of the state that caused a test to fail. And when you change a feature related to one test you will have to run all the previous tests just to know if your feature works. Cucumber just does a good job of helping you stay on the right track IMHO.

Comment: I don't intend to make a feature depend on another feature. I intend to create a beforeAllScenarios block that sits in one feature, which is what I thought 'background' was but isn't. What you are talking about - 'not isolating tests' is another level which I don't tend to cross.